# Heroku - hosting a java app with a native shared library

Tags: java, heroku

I have a Java web app that uses a shared native library (.dll on Windows, .jnilib on Mac OS). Is it possible to host the app on Heroku?

How do I point to the library? Is it the usual way by adding a VM argument:

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/library
```

Comment: How do you point to the library locally? Is it with the `-Djava.library.path` option?

Comment: Yes, however I run it on Mac OS using a jnilib file.

Comment: Do you have a `.so` file or something for Linux (which is the OS Heroku uses)?

Comment: Yes, I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Djava.library.path` option will work on Heroku. You'll probably put it in your `Procfile` or in whatever command you use to run the app, like:

```
web: java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/library -jar myapp.jar
```

But you'll also need to upload the Linux binary to Heroku. If you're using Maven, I recommend following a guide to [using native libraries with Maven](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2011/01/native-libraries-with-maven.html). There [are many](http://web.archive.org/web/20120308042202/http://www.buildanddeploy.com/node/17).

If you are deploying with the [Heroku CLI](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-deploy) and the `heroku jar:deploy` or similar commands, then you can use the `--includes` option. Run `heroku help jar` for more info.